# How to use TokenSequencePattern

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I'm just getting started with CoreNLP's TokenSequencePattern and I can't get simple matches to work. All im trying to do is to match a token from the input text. The code below executes without errors but doesn't match anything. However, if u change the match expression to *[]* then it matches the two sentences.

```
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse");
     StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
     Annotation document = new Annotation("This is sent 1. And here is sent 2");
     pipeline.annotate(document);
     List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

     Env env = TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv();
     env.setDefaultStringMatchFlags(NodePattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     env.setDefaultStringPatternFlags(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

     TokenSequencePattern pattern = TokenSequencePattern.compile(env,"[ { word:\"sent\" } ]");
     TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = pattern.getMatcher(sentences);

     while ( matcher.find() ) {
        System.out.println( matcher.group() );
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
List<CoreLabel> tokens = 
document.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);
TokenSequencePattern pattern= TokenSequencePattern.compile("[ { 
word:\"sent\" } ]");
TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = pattern.getMatcher(tokens);
while (matcher.find())
{
String matchedString = matcher.group();
List<CoreMap> matchedTokens = matcher.groupNodes();
System.out.println(matchedString + " " + matchedTokens);
}
```

Comment: Even if the code is correct, it always helps to write some text explaining why this is the answer.